# PHP set multipart or form data

Tags: php

I am trying to work with a html file using the following but I am having an issue doing it with the PHP api. I already have the files ready on the server but I cannot figure out how to set the multipart/form data using the following code to do the conversion. Lets say I have a html file in the same folder how do I use it in the following code for conversion.

Code for conversion :

```
<?php
//set POST variables 
$fields = array('from' => 'markdown',
        'to' => 'pdf',
        'input_files[]' => "@/".realpath('markdown.md').";type=text/x-markdown; charset=UTF-8"
        );

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //needed so that the $result=curl_exec() output is the file and isn't just true/false

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Are you forgetting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);`?

Comment: Also, what version PHP are you using?

Comment: @miken32 I am using 5.4 version. I do not know how to use the html file in the same folder using the above code. I just wanted to know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PHP 5.5, the `@` format for specifying a file path is no longer valid, and the value will be sent as a raw string. Instead try [`curl_file_create`](http://php.net/curl_file_create). Also, regardless of version, don't forget to set `CURLOPT_POST` variable to true as well. This code also assumes you have read access to the file being uploaded.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://c.docverter.com/convert';
$fields = [
    'from' => 'markdown',
    'to' => 'pdf',
    'input_files[]' => (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50500) ? '@' . realpath('markdown.md') : curl_file_create('markdown.md')
];
$result_file = 'uploads/result.pdf';

//open connection
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $fields,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents($result_file, $result);
```